# Error in cloning django-oscar

Tags: django, github, django-oscar

I get this when I try to clone django-oscar. what should I do ?

```
Cloning into 'django-oscar'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '183.39.256.900' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Did you try to search for the answer?

Comment: @Bibhas yup..[this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) and [this](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: @Bibhas I'm getting this when I do clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 'Usage: clip [-v axisx,y,z,...] [-g value] [-l value] [-s nslices[,fraction]]
        [-sph centerx,y,z,...] [-cyl centerx,y,z,...] [-e] [file.oogl]
Reads an OOGL object from file.oogl (or stdin if omitted).
Slices it against a (series of) planes whose normal vectors are given
    by the -v argument (default 1,0,0,0,...).
Given -g, selects portions where <point> dot <vector> > <pvalue>.
Given -l, selects portions where <point> dot <vector> < <nvalue>.
Given both, takes the portion lying between t...'

Comment: @Bibhas still ca't figure out what to do

Comment: just `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and add the key to your github account. and configure.

Comment: You should probably provide the command (including repository URL) you use to clone the repository.

Comment: @Bibhas Thanks a Lot Bro.. It worked..even I'm Indian frm Mumbai..cheers :)

Comment: @user2539745 adding it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your public key to github.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

and add the key to your github account. and configure.